# Orthogonality of Sub Sections of Orthogonal Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a sent of $ N $ orthogonal vectors $ {\left \{ {v}_{i} \right \}}_{i = 1}^{N}, \ {v}_{i} \in R^{N} $

Now, let's say K samples of the same index (Lets say j = 51:100, where N = 200) are removed from each of the vectors:

$$ {v}_{i}^{'} = {v}_{i} \left [ 1:50, 101:200 \right ] $$

And still keep N - K vectors orthogonal no matter what indices I chose to remove?
Can we build such vectors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard basis satisfies this property.  Consider the standard basis $\{e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_N\}$.  Now, no matter which elements of all the vectors you choose to keep, the remaining vectors are orthogonal (assuming we're using the dot product as the inner product).

Of course, some of the remaining vectors will be the $0$ vector.  But still, the dot product of the zero vector with an vector is $0$, and so those vectors are orthogonal to all the vectors remaining in the set.

Comment: Hi, You're correct. I didn't write the question correctly which gives this trivial solution. Anyhow, marked your answer.